# Alignment problem in logic circuit

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

I am trying to compile an overview about logic gates. I have read the manual and studied a lot of examples. I failed, however, to achieve a satisfying result.

Here is my current code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.IEC}

\usepackage{amsopn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\AND}{\wedge}
\DeclareMathOperator{\OR}{\vee}
\DeclareMathOperator{\XOR}{\underline{\vee}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\NOT}{\neg}

\begin{document}

Davor

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic IEC]
\draw [help lines] grid (12,7);
% Gates
\node at (1, 6) [buffer gate] (g11) {}; 
\node at (8, 6) [not gate]    (g12) {}; 
\node at (1, 4) [and gate]    (g21) {};
\node at (8, 4) [nand gate]   (g22) {}; 
\node at (1, 2) [or gate]     (g31) {}; 
\node at (8, 2) [nor gate]    (g32) {}; 
\node at (1, 0) [xor gate]    (g41) {}; 
\node at (8, 0) [xnor gate]   (g42) {}; 
% Inputs
\node at ([xshift=-1cm] g11.input) (g11-a) {$A$}; \draw (g11.input) -- (g11-a);
\node at ([xshift=-1cm] g12.input) (g12-a) {$A$}; \draw (g12.input) -- (g12-a);
\foreach \gate in {g21, g22, g31, g32, g41, g42}
{
  \node at ([xshift=-1cm] \gate.input 1) (\gate-a) {$A$}; \draw (\gate.input 1) -- (\gate-a);
  \node at ([xshift=-1cm] \gate.input 2) (\gate-b) {$B$}; \draw (\gate.input 2) -- (\gate-b);
};
% Outputs
\node at ([xshift=1.7cm] g11.output) (g11-y) {$Y = A$}; \draw (g11.output) -- (g11-y);
\node at ([xshift=1.7cm] g12.output) (g12-y) {$Y = \NOT A$}; \draw (g12.output) -- (g12-y);
\node at ([xshift=1.7cm] g21.output) (g21-y) {$Y = A \AND B$}; \draw (g21.output) -- (g21-y);
\node at ([xshift=1.7cm] g22.output) (g22-y) {$Y = \NOT \left( A \AND B \right)$}; \draw (g22.output) -- (g22-y);
\node at ([xshift=1.7cm] g31.output) (g31-y) {$Y = A \OR B$}; \draw (g31.output) -- (g31-y);
\node at ([xshift=1.7cm] g32.output) (g32-y) {$Y = \NOT \left( A \OR B \right)$}; \draw (g32.output) -- (g32-y);
\node at ([xshift=1.7cm] g41.output) (g41-y) {$Y = A \XOR B$}; \draw (g41.output) -- (g41-y);
\node at ([xshift=1.7cm] g42.output) (g42-y) {$Y = \NOT \left( A \XOR B \right)$}; \draw (g42.output) -- (g42-y);
\end{tikzpicture}

Danach

\end{document}
```

What I would like to improve is

1. the alignment of the "Y = " labels;
2. the use of relative units instead of cm in the xshift;
3. the alignment of the "A" and "B" labels with respect to the surrounding text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For questions 1 and 3, change the way the things are drawn. First draw the line and then put the node like

   ```
   \draw[shorten >= 3pt] (g11.input) -- +(-1cm,0) 
                          node[outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,anchor=east] (g11-a) {$A$};
   ```

   Also make `inner xsep` and `outer sep` both zero for question 3. Additionally you may shorten the line to leave some gap between `A`s and `B`s and the line.
2. For 2, use `positioning` library and the `right = of` and `below = of` syntax.

With these your code will be,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.IEC,positioning}

\usepackage{amsopn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\AND}{\wedge}
\DeclareMathOperator{\OR}{\vee}
\DeclareMathOperator{\XOR}{\underline{\vee}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\NOT}{\neg}

\begin{document}

Davor

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic IEC]
\draw [help lines] grid (12,7);
% Gates
\node at (1, 6) [buffer gate] (g11) {};
\node[right = 6cm of g11]  [not gate]    (g12) {};
\node [below = of g11] [and gate]    (g21) {};
\node [below = of g12] [nand gate]   (g22) {};
\node [below = of g21] [or gate]     (g31) {};
\node [below = of g22] [nor gate]    (g32) {};
\node [below = of g31] [xor gate]    (g41) {};
\node [below = of g32] [xnor gate]   (g42) {};
% Inputs
\draw[shorten >= 3pt] (g11.input) -- +(-1cm,0) node[outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,anchor=east] (g11-a) {$A$};
\draw[shorten >= 3pt] (g12.input) -- +(-1cm,0) node[outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,anchor=east] (g12-a) {$A$};
\foreach \gate in {g21, g22, g31, g32, g41, g42}
{
  \draw[shorten >= 3pt] (\gate.input 1) -- +(-1cm,0) node[outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,anchor=east] (\gate-a) {$A$};
  \draw[shorten >= 3pt] (\gate.input 2) -- +(-1cm,0) node[outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,anchor=east] (\gate-b) {$B$};
};
% Outputs
\draw[shorten >= 3pt] (g11.output) -- +(1cm,0) node[outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,anchor=west] (g11-y) {$Y = A$};
\draw[shorten >= 3pt] (g12.output) -- +(1cm,0) node[outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,anchor=west] (g12-y) {$Y = \NOT A$};
\draw[shorten >= 3pt] (g21.output) -- +(1cm,0) node[outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,anchor=west] (g21-y) {$Y = A \AND B$};
\draw[shorten >= 3pt] (g22.output) -- +(1cm,0) node[outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,anchor=west] (g22-y) {$Y = \NOT \left( A \AND B \right)$};
\draw[shorten >= 3pt] (g31.output) -- +(1cm,0) node[outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,anchor=west] (g31-y) {$Y = A \OR B$};
\draw[shorten >= 3pt] (g32.output) -- +(1cm,0) node[outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,anchor=west] (g32-y) {$Y = \NOT \left( A \OR B \right)$};
\draw[shorten >= 3pt] (g41.output) -- +(1cm,0) node[outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,anchor=west] (g41-y) {$Y = A \XOR B$};
\draw[shorten >= 3pt] (g42.output) -- +(1cm,0) node[outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,anchor=west] (g42-y) {$Y = \NOT \left( A \XOR B \right)$};

\end{tikzpicture}

Danach

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And never use `minimal` class until you are very sure about what you are doing.